# How to create runtime columns in a known SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, wpf, entity-framework

In my WPF application, I'm using Entity Framework.

I would like to create a new bool column in a known table at runtime.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me a link where i can study the way?

Comment: My question is why do you think you need to add a new column at runtime? That has the telltale signs of a poor design. Tables are designed to store data, if they are constantly changing then it makes getting that data difficult.

Comment: because I register  for each user the hours worked.
it is not said that the hours are consecutive.
I thought about creating 24 bool fields but most of the time they would be false and since I have a lot of users I would not use memory for anything.
so I thought to create the field only when it is true.

Comment: Not sure I follow. The bit datatype (there is no such thing as a boolean datatype in t-sql) takes almost no storage as it is. And columns can't change row by row so once your code runs 24 times all the overhead of conditionally adding columns is wasted. I would rather use a table that records start and end time. Storing each hour like this is non-standard and will force you to do some really ugly gyrations to use the data for anything.

Comment: I thank you, I will follow your advice